# Creating procedure or function in Ada task

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, task, ada

I am creating the following task in Ada and I want it to contain a procedure that tells me the count of my buffer. How can I do that?

```
package body Buffer is

  task body Buffer is

    size: constant := 10000; -- buffer capacity
    buf: array(1.. size) of Types.Item;
    count: integer range 0..size := 0;
    in_index,out_index:integer range 1..size := 1;

  begin
    procedure getCount(currentCount: out Integer) is
    begin   
      currentCount := count;
    end getCount;   

    loop
      select
        when count<size =>
          accept put(item: in Types.Item) do
            buf(in_index) := item;
          end put;
          in_index := in_index mod size+1;
          count := count + 1;
        or
          when count>0 =>
            accept get(item:out Types.Item) do
              item := buf(out_index);
            end get;
            out_index := out_index mod size+1;
            count := count - 1;
        or
          terminate;
      end select;
    end loop;
  end Buffer;

end Buffer;
```

When I compile this code I get an error that

> declarations must come before "begin"

referring to the definition of the `getCount` procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A declaration must come before "begin", and your declaration of "getCount" is *following* the "begin". Relocate it:

```
procedure getCount(currentCount: out Integer) is
begin   
    currentCount := count;
end getCount;   

begin
```

But really, pay attention to trashgod's advice.

Answer (score 6):

The immediate problem is that you have specified a [*subprogram body*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-6-3.html) <strike>without having first specified a corresponding [*subprogram declaration*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-6-1.html)</strike> in the *handled sequence of statements* part of your [*task body*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-9-1.html). It should go in the *declarative part*, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371954/230513).

The larger problem appears to be creating a bounded buffer, for which a [*protected type*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-9-4.html) seems more suitable. Examples may be found in [*§II.9 Protected Types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#9) and [*§9.1 Protected Types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-9.html#1). In `protected type Bounded_Buffer`, you could add a

```
function Get_Count return Integer;
```

having a body like this:

```
function Get_Count return Integer is
begin
   return Count;
end Get_Count;
```